# How do I instrument my code for Splunk metrics?

Tags: metrics, splunk

I'm brand new to Splunk, having worked exclusively with Prometheus before. The one obvious thing I can't see from looking at the Splunk website is how in my code, I create/expose a metric... if I must provide an HTTP endpoint for consumption, or call into some API to push values, etc. Further, I cannot see which languages Splunk provide libraries for, in order to aid instrumentation - I cannot see where all this low level stuff is documented!

Can anyone help me understand how Splunk works, particularly how it compares to Prometheus?

Comment: This is a nice question, but isn't a fit for SO - and likely wouldn't fit on SF or SU, either (especially when asking for comparisons to another tool)

Comment: I'm asking how I write code to instrument metrics. We already have a tag. If course it's an appropriate question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, programs write their normal log files and Splunk ingests those files so they can be searched and data extracted.

There are other ways to get data into Splunk, though.  See https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/reference for the SDKs available in a few languages.

You could write your metrics to collectd and then send them to Splunk.  See https://splunkonbigdata.com/2020/05/09/metrics-data-collection-via-collectd-part-2/

You could write your metrics directly to Splunk using their HTTP Event Collector (HEC).  See https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/httpeventcollector/